# R - interval counts

Tags: r

I'm using the function

```
table(cut(data$col1, breaks = seq.int(from = 0, to = 16, by = 1)))
```

and I'm getting the intervals like

```
(0,1]
(1,2]
...
```

But is there a way to make my first interval to include 0 so that it would be [0,1]?
And how would I change all the intervals to include the first numbers? [0,1] [1,2], ...

Comment: use `include.lowest = TRUE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `include.lowest` as `TRUE`

```
table(cut(data$col1, breaks = seq.int(from = 0, to = 16, by = 1), 
        include.lowest = TRUE))
```

---

Using a small reproducible example

```
set.seed(24)
v1 <- sample(0:19, 100, replace = TRUE)
table(cut(v1, breaks = seq.int(from = 0, to = 16, by = 1), include.lowest = TRUE))
#  [0,1]   (1,2]   (2,3]   (3,4]   (4,5]   (5,6]   (6,7]   (7,8]   (8,9]  (9,10] (10,11] (11,12] (12,13] (13,14] (14,15] (15,16] 
#     13       7       5       6       3       7       6       5       5       3       3       3       5       3       4       5
```

Comment: Thank you! I realized I wanted all of my intervals to be in brackets. Would the argument then be include = TRUE?

Comment: @musiklover it would be for all the intervals to include the lower interval

Comment: Sorry, what would be the code to include the lower interval for all the intervals?

Comment: @musiklover the `include.lowest = TRUE` is doing that for all the intervals